# Blender 2.8 VSE scene strip preview does not show image (as plane) from 3D viewport

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In scene1 I have a simple image as plane + some extruded text; eg the title. The number of frames is set to 90. When I add a this scene strip in the VSE, I can only preview the text. The image itself is displayed as a white plane. When I add a camera and render a frame of this strip, I can see both the image and the title. Is it possible to preview also the image in the VSE while scrubbing through the strip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open Properties panel (press <kbd>N</kbd>), select scene strip, then find in Properties panel Scene **Preview/render tab**. You can set here **Render** or **LookDev** to view the textures

Note, Sequencer must be in **Preview** or **Sequenser/Preview** mode

[image]

Comment: I can't find this Scene Preview/Render tab. Scene > Filter > Annotations > Custom properties. No scene preview/Render or Safe Areas tab. I' m working in the latest version (2.8.51). Is your screenshot from a previous version? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sequencer must be in **Preview** or **Sequenser/Preview** mode

Comment: Great! Thanks. In the default Video editing workspace, you can set the Properties panel of the top window; where you can see/preview your video. This window is already in Preview mode.